# Every day, I get repeated notifications about my answers being migrated or posts edited

Tags: bug, migration, global-inbox

Every day, when I take a look at my notifications on stackexchange.com I see the same set of answer migration notifications appearing over and over:

[image: Repeated notifications - example]

(They start out marked unread, this is just after I clicked on the menu).

Other notifications appear to be hidden or fail to appear. A while later, they appear, but seem to be already marked read, e.g.

[image: After refresh]

These notifications get marked read, but seem to reappear the next day.

It's been happening for about a week.

Update: If I visit stackoverflow.com first, instead of stackexchange.com, it does not seem to happen. Furthermore, it only seems to happen after the UTC midnight roll-over, not during the day.

Anyone else seeing the same?

In the unlikely event that it might matter, I'm running Chrome 31.0.1650.39 beta on Fedora 19 x64.

Comment: I saw something like this today, but my inbox showed old election notices. I think what happened is all _comments_ were omitted from display, but still marked as read on the server.

Comment: @KevinReid Yes, I think you're right, as I also seem to see "post edited" notices. I've also found that it only seems to happen on stackexchange.com its self, not stackoverflow.com, and only if I visit stackexchange.com first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this never got any answer, but at some point went away on its own.

Internal DB consistency issues or an isolated bug I guess.